# Broadcast Receiver Not receive messages from Mobile default messags application Why?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms, smsmanager

In BroadcastReceiver i want to receive sms from default Mobile application.

But when user send sms without internet connect then i receive, but when user (send sms via wifi or Mobile Network) i unable to read message.

```
public class MessageReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static MessageListener mListener;
public static final String reciveSMS="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
public static final String TAG ="SmsBroadcastReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("fsdfdsfdsfdgfdsg  ","  rerwerw");
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        String formate = data.getString("format");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
             {
                smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], formate);
            } else {
                smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            String message = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Message Received: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have't understand why i face this problem , because Broadcast receiver can send or receive broadcast messages from the Android system and other Android apps. It only receive (sms without using internet), But every mobile messages application have default enable option(Use wifi or data for messaging when available).

Anyone please help ***receive sms from default Mobile Messages Application***

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're asking, but your app only works with SMS specifically. It does not work with MMS, RCS, or whatever other types of messages that your actual messaging app can handle. Are you sure that the messages you're missing are SMS? Most messaging apps these days rarely use SMS all the time, but those are the only ones that you have any access to. You can't really spy on user's messages anymore without being their main SMS app, and therefore a full-blown messaging client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already register your receiver yet?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    registerReceiver(messageReciver , new  IntentFilter(YOUR FILTER));
}
```

---

try this

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application>
    // add this
    <receiver android:name=".MessageReciver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: no, i try this but i have same issue

Comment: hyy , i have edit my Q please review again.

Comment: i edit my answer, please try again.

Answer (score 1):

It's true, since some month before I have the same problem. If wifi is off and LTE is off, then MMS and SMS actions are broadcasted with sms_received or wap_push_received are recognized by broadcast receiver intent.

In new Smartphones these messages are marked by green color.

But if the sender phone turn on wifi or turn on LTE data mode, then shit happens.

These sms or mms over wifi or over LTE are now CHAT messages. These chat messages are not broadcasted by sms_received or wap_push_received. These CHAT messages are blue marked on modern phones. If you try to send messages (sms or mms) to an smartphone with wifi off or LTE off, you will be informed that now your messages will be send only as normal SMS or MMS.

You can find these CHAT messages over contentresolver content://im/chat

Unfortunately I doesn't know yet, how to receive broadcasted chat messages. For now I pull every 1 second the contentresolver for new chat messages.

Comment: Hi marian , could you help me more with how you can be used content resolver for new chat messages.

Comment: Do you know if your answer is still true after RCS has been implemented as default protocol? I'm trying to get a list of messages regardless of type, have the sms and mms sorted, but this is the first time I've seen the content://im/chat location.